# Volumes in docker-compose not working on Windows 7

Tags: docker, windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization

Here's a sample `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    image: docker-test
    container_name: docker-test
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/app
```

Here's the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch

COPY . /srv/app
COPY docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/app \
    && a2enmod rewrite
```

There are no errors in running this except file changes in `.` are not reflected in realtime inside the container `/src/app`. Any ideas what's wrong  with it?

Comment: Do you mean to have `/srv` in the Dockerfile and `/src` in the `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: @DavidMaze They're actually both `/srv` it was just a typo in this question.

Answer (score 0):

For those who care, apparently the default setup in Docker Toolbox for Windows 7 doesn't read outside `C:/Users` so you have to manually setup the shared folders in VirtualBox. This [article](http://support.divio.com/local-development/docker/how-to-use-a-directory-outside-cusers-with-docker-toolboxdocker-for-windows) helped me.

Once you set that up, your `docker-compose.yml` file needs to be like this:

```
volumes:
  - <shared-folder>:/srv/app
```

Replace `<shared-folder>` with the name of the shared folder in VirtualBox.